# How should a rewrite rule look like in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I want the visitors to `sub.example.com` to be redirected to

```
https://sub.example.com:9545
```

Is this possible with `.htaccess`? If so how should it look?

Answer (score 0):

To "redirect" all visitors from `sub.example.com` to `https://sub.example.com:9545`, whilst maintaining the URL-path (I assume) then you could do something like the following in `.htaccess` using mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}:9545%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L]
```

However, I wonder if you meant "rewrite" (as in *internal redirect*), rather "redirect" (as in external HTTP redirect) - do you wish the user to see the port?

If you wish the port to be hidden from the user then you can't simply *rewrite* the request, you need to configure your server as a reverse proxy and proxy the request to `https://sub.example.com:9545` using mod_proxy. This does require some additional server configuration.